# What is the proper schema.org markup for a webpage about another website?

Tags: schema.org

Most comments and usage about schema.org:Website refer to using it to refer to your own website. Some have even said that it can only be used to refer to your own website.

But, what if you have a web page that talks about another website? For example, what if you have a review about that website? Or what if your page is an analysis of that website's code?

Can you use schema.org:Website to let bots know that this page is about that website?

Is there any example code? Is the following example the proper way to do it?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Webpage",
  "name": "Website Analysis for example.com",
  "description": "An SEO analysis of the code on example.com.",
  "about": {
    "@type": "Website",
    "name": "example.com",
    "url": "http://example.com"
  }
}
</script>
```

Note: Their website is example.com. My website has a different domain.

Comment: No issue with the example. Nothing in schema data model limits `@Webpage` link to `@Website`. Further, `@Website` could be `subjectOf` `@Webpage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of what you're listing here is:

> An SEO analysis of the code on example.com.

To me, I think it would make more sense to use [Article](https://schema.org/Article) in this case as it can be considered an investigative report. Maybe even [Report](https://schema.org/Report) (but I'm not sure how that's handled by search engines, if that is your intent)

The only downside of using article is you'll have to fill out more information such as `publisher` and `datePublished`. If you want to reference the website you are reviewing, I think using [About](https://schema.org/about) would make the most sense. For example:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "author": "John Doe",
  "headline": "SEO overview for example.com",
  "datePublished":"05/07/2020",
  "image":"articleimage.jpg",
  "publisher": { 
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "My Company Name",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "mycompanylogo.jpg"
    }
  },
  "about": {
    "@type": "Webpage",
    "name": "Example.com",
    "url": "http://example.com"
  }
}
</script>
```